# How to re-arrange line in data file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file like this:

```
File name 
Columns   Rows
2         1500
line 1        20
line 2        10
line 3        30
line 4        50    ! this line need to move up
line 5        40
line 6        70
line 7        80
line 8        90    ! this line need to move up
line 9        20
line 10       10
line 11       30
line 12       50    ! this line need to move up
line 13       40    
line 14       70
line 15       80
line 16       90    ! this line need to move up
.....
```

I want to re-arrange lines like following. After each circle of 4 lines, the last line of each circle move to first line.

```
File name 
Columns   Rows
2         1500
line 4        50    ! after arranged
line 1        20
line 2        10
line 3        30
line 8        90    ! after arranged
line 5        40
line 6        70
line 7        80
line 12       50    ! after arranged
line 9        20
line 10       10
line 11       30
line 16       90    ! after arranged
line 13       40
line 14       70
line 15       80
.....
.....
```

Could you please help me? I really appreciate you help!
Thank you so much!
Best wishes and regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by using generator functions. A generator function is a function that implicitly returns (that means that we do not have to return ourselves) an iterable object called generator. Generator items will be marked with `yield` statements in the generator function. Performance wise generator are very good as they are lazy. They will not compute all the elements and return a list, instead they will compute each element when it needs it.

```
from collections import deque

def rearrange(iterable, block_size, shift=1, skip_initial=0):
    buffer = deque()
    for item in iterable:
        if skip_initial > 0:
            skip_initial -= 1
            yield item
            continue
        buffer.append(item)
        if len(buffer) == block_size:
            buffer.rotate(shift)
            while len(buffer):
                yield buffer.popleft()
    # Handle extra items here, you may want to rotate less times, or not rotate them at all
    while len(buffer):
        yield buffer.popleft()
```

The first thing we do is pass the intial lines unchanged. For that we reduce a counter, yield the line and continue, which mean skip to the next element in the loop. After that we make a buffer `collections.deque` has been selected as the buffer type as it works similar to a list but with good performance inserting and deleting from both ends and with the `rotate` method we need. When this buffer has the number of items we specify as the `block_size`, we rotate them, and we yield them 1 by 1 extracting it from the buffer. After the loop we yield the items that may still remain in the buffer as we may not have a multiple of 4. You may want to rotate these items too, in that case just add a `buffer.rotate(shift)` where the comment is.

The usage would be:

```
f = [
    'File name',
    'Columns   Rows',
    '2         1500',
    'line 1        20',
    'line 2        10',
    'line 3        30',
    'line 4        50',
    'line 5        40',
    'line 6        70',
    'line 7        80',
    'line 8        90',
    'line 9        20',
    'line 10       10',
    'line 11       30',
    'line 12       50',
    'line 13       40',
    'line 14       70',
    'line 15       80',
    'line 16       90',
]

for line in rearrange(f, block_size=4, shift=1, skip_initial=3):
    print(line)
```

`f` is a list that represents your example file, but you should be able to use the file pointer itself:

```
with open('path/to/input', 'r') as input, open('path/to/output', 'w') as output:
    for line in rearrange(input, block_size=4, shift=1, skip_initial=3):
        output.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: Hello, I tried it but no error or line was shown, just '<generator object rearrange at 0x11037d840>'

Comment: @BinhThien I added a usage section to show how it would be used.

Comment: @BinhThien Were you able to make this work? The last three lines should be pretty much your usecase.